# Unable to lock row - Record currently unavailable error

Tags: apex, process-builder, record, locking

I know there has been lot of things available online for record locking errors but I am putting my analysis based on client issue that we are facing, would appreciate if I can get any thoughts.

We have one visual-force page we name it as Survey Program Page and inside that we have table where in user can configure multiple criteria s by adding multiple rows as in say e.g

```
Row 1 - Account.Name = "xyz"
Row 2 - Account.Email__c = "test@test.com"
```

We have process builder at backed on Account which has `@InvocableMethod` which creates custom object record by taking AccountId.

There is also one Trigger on account which do some manipulation on Account record.

```
As per order of execution Trigger will execute first then Process builder.
```

Now, User creates Account record with
 `Account.Name = "xyz"` &  `Account.Email__c = "test@test.com"`

First, Account Trigger will be executed and it will do its processing.
Second, Process builder will be executed, `@InvocableMethod` will create custom object record by taking AccountId

We are receiving error `UNABLE TO LOCK ROW` when `@InvocableMethod` tries to create custom object record.

I believe Account Trigger will place lock first on Account Record.

> A given transaction can only wait a maximum of 10 seconds for a lock
>   to be released, otherwise it will time out.

I have following questions in my mind

1. Are we receiving error because Account trigger is taking longer than 10 sec to release lock before it passes Account Record to process builder `@InvocableMethod` method  ?
2. How does locking work internally ? does each process puts lock and every other process can wait maximum up to 10 sec before previous process release its lock, if its more than 10 sec then next process will throw error as `UNABLE TO LOCK ROW` or `UNABLE TO OBTAIN EXCLUSIVE ACCESS OF THIS RECORD`

If this is the case then what would be the ideal approach to deal with this scenario.

1. Should we work on optimizing code for Account Trigger so that execution time/ locking period will reduce to less than 10 sec.
2. Is there something that we can do inside process builder so that we can avoid record locking errors.

Thoughts!

Comment: As a quick-fix you can go for a scheduled action on the process builder to call the invocable method combined with a execution context variable. As a long term fix you should investigate more on the concurrent records access and try to control the execution chaining

Comment: Thanks for information, it might help me to deal with this scenario, will check around this.

Comment: Once the record is locked for update in the Visualforce page, the lock is maintained through the entire transaction, including your triggers, process builder, invocable action, etc. It's likely that the record is locked because someone else is using it at the same time.

Comment: @sfdcfox ahh I might be misleading by adding information of VF page, on page we just set criteria for Sobject. Actual transaction starts when user creates Sobject record.
We are getting issue inside in-vocable method at Insert statement because what I believe Account Trigger might be holding lock on Account record too long so when it comes to execution of process builder , its throwing error "Unable To Lock Row",
Is it the case ? Please advise.

Comment: No, whatever is going on in the trigger has nothing to do with the process builder/invocable action. The lock applies to the entire transaction. In other words, you have another transaction that's holding up the record. Without seeing all the code, it'd be hard to tell what's going on. You need two separate transactions in order to get this error.

Comment: @sfdcfox Another thing that I saw inside clients org is client is having Two processes on Account object I mean one is ours which has invocable method and another is doing something else, could it be a cause ? I am curious how SF determines which process to execute first!

Comment: @NachiketDeshpande The Process Builder executes in arbitrary order. Again, the records are locked the entire transaction, so no, you wouldn't get row lock errors because of multiple processes or invocable actions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75971/discussion-between-nachiket-deshpande-and-sfdcfox).

Comment: @sfdcfox I went ahead and investigated further by logging case with SF support what I found is on Salesforce server logs I can see that there is transaction getting Timed out.
Since we have similar process for all objects we investigated for one of the opportunity record Opportunity --> Contact are related object
there is field "phoneDetail__c" on Contact object which is being updated by batch process.
"

Comment: I observed that its taking time around 18 sec or more
since contact is being locked by this process which means it will also lock its related objects which is Opportunity
and if during that process we tries to edit opportunity record as Invocable method has to wait for more than 10 sec , transaction will be timed out and it will throw "Unable To Lock row error,
Is it correct conclusion?